# What does the "だった" in "だったっけ" mean?

Tags: grammar

From what I can find out, たっけ is just an expression that shows that you're trying to remember something, but what does the だった part mean? I have a few guesses, but they don't seem to match what I can understand from it.

> 今日一限から英語だったっけ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The particle **-kke** is an interrogatory particle that marks a recollection, or the failure thereof, in the case a question word appears. The particle's usage is often introspective: the speaker asks him/herself whether something is recollected properly.
Recollections are usually about the past, but it is possible to ask oneself whether a certain event in the future, or a state that ranges from the past into the present, is properly recalled. In that case, many languages use past tense to mark the non-past event.
The particle *-kke* often appears with **-da**, or its past form **-dat-ta**, as in the OP's example *eigo-dat-ta-kke*. In the form *-dat-ta-kke*, past tense **-dat-ta** emphasizes the function of introspective speech marked by **-kke**. Translations into English can then use the past tense, and possibly the adverb **again**:

> 何だったっけ
> nan-dat-ta-kke
> 'What was (that) again?'

The OP's example must be understood in one specific way. The example is repeated below:

> 今日（の）１限（目）から英語だったっけ？
> 'Was it English from the first period today?'

Since the example contains 今日 **きょう**, rather than 今朝 **けさ**, we can infer that the speaker asks **before** class. S/He is trying to recollect whether English is the first subject of the day. In that case, the speaker tries to recollect (remembered) data of a future event. Even though the event is about the future, the past tense **-dat-ta** serves to emphasizes the introspective function of **-kke**. The English translation shows that using the past tense in these situations is not unique to Japanese.

Comment: note that this is not formal.

Answer (score 1):

It directly translates to "it was so". Used to state a fact.

> Ex: 昨日は休みだった。(It was a holiday yesterday)

It directly translates to　"was/is it?" When you say だったっけ it becomes a question.

> Ex: 今日休みだったっけ？ (Is it a holiday today?)