# What is the difference in meaning between じゃなかった vs じゃない?

Tags: grammar

**Context:**

It was agreed upon that there will be a class meeting at 4.30pm later. However, someone wrote the wrong time on the blackboard. And so, one of the characters replied:

これ４時半からじゃなかったっけ？

My **question** is, why is じゃなかった used instead of じゃない? Could anyone provide a brief description on the nuance difference between the two?

I understand how じゃない and じゃなかった works when referring to state-of-beings, but when put in a question context, I am unable to comprehend the nuance it has.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "だった" in "だったっけ" mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21000/what-does-the-%e3%81%a0%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f-in-%e3%81%a0%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a3%e3%81%91-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this た is a modal-た described in the following questions and articles.

- [Non conventional usage of the past tense](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40733/5010)
- [Usage of plain i-adjectives or た form (悪かったｖ悪い、良かったｖいい etc）](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21347/5010)
- [Conjugated word + んだ vs nonconjugated word + conjugated んだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60788/5010)
- [Wasabi - Another Function of the Ta-form: Discovery and Recall](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/another-function-of-the-ta-form-discovery-and-recall/)

Saying "4時半からじゃない?" is also perfectly grammatical (and is more neutral in a sense), but saying "4時半からじゃなかった?" means the speaker is trying to recall something and possibly update his existing belief. In other words, with this た, the speaker is showing his surprise that his memory may be wrong.

You cannot use った when there is no prior expectation/knowledge. For example, when someone made a simple calculation mistake like "25×70=1250", you can say "1750じゃない?" but not "1750じゃなかった(っけ)?"

っけ has a similar purpose and it is commonly used with た/だ. But it's optional, as shown above.

Comment: I was reviewing the links you provided, I would like to clarify if the use of modal た also applies to prior expectations that are in sync with current expectations? For example, you are recalling about the time of the meeting being 4.30, and it turns out it was really 4.30. Can I still use the modal た in this case?

Answer (score -1):

## 日本語

日本語での回答になります。

じゃない＝でない、じゃなかっけ（じゃなかったか）＝ではないか

前者は否定、後者は確認として使っていると思います。

また、約束事の時間には影響されません。

## English

じゃない = でない / じゃなかっけ（じゃなかったか） = ではないか

The former would be used as negation, and the latter confirmation.

It is not affected by the time the event takes place.

Comment: I can't understand the answer in Japanese

Comment: The former is a denial, the latter a confirmation.

Comment: If possible, could you edit your answer to be in English to reflect what you just mentioned and provide an example or two for better understanding?

Comment: I believe じゃない can also be used as a confirmation? I just wanted to know what is the difference when used in the present and past state for both of them

Comment: ではないか＝さっきそう言ったではないか(Did you say that earlier?)

Comment: `I believe じゃない can also be used as a confirmation?` Yes, you're right. And in this case they're interchangable and the nuance difference is little. But so far I don't know how to explain that little difference well...

Comment: interchangable→interchangeable

Comment: あくまで否定疑問文における「明日じゃない？」と「明日じゃなかった？」にどんな差があるのか、を聞かれています。どちらも未来の予定の確認だという点では同じですが、微妙なニュアンスの差があるので、そこに言及しないといけないと思います。（これ多分、慣れてないネイティブには相当難易度の高い質問だと思います…）

Comment: 改めて調べて見ました。
じゃない＝ではない→否定の判断を表す。
じゃなかった＝ではないか->1.疑問・反問・詰問の意を表す。
2.勧誘の意を表す。
相違点として、事実に対しての疑問や問い直しや問い詰める強調した表現と思います。またじゃなかったには変更されたことに対する小さな怒り・不満も含まれているかもしれません。
@narutoさん私は語学力が不足しているので、支援をお願いします！

Comment: よく使う例として、予定は4時半からじゃなかった？俺、もうその後予定入れているんだけど！

Comment: はい、その「じゃなかった？」についてですね。これ辞書引いた程度では到底出てこない話題でして、日本語だと[こんな記事](http://www.cocopb.com/NichiNichi/journal_1/%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC/2010/5/5_%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%EF%BC%8F%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E6%95%99%E8%82%B2%E7%A0%94%E7%A9%B6__1__2010_files/2010_1_sadanobu.pdf)があります。知識修正のタ、思い出しのタ、などと呼ばれる用法です。僕はこのサイトに入り浸り始めて3年目位にやっと知りました…

Comment: @naruto さん情報共有有難うございます。この例は「態度説」ですね。私は言語学者ではありませんが、、